# How to add (Dot) .Com in href

Tags: jquery, html

How to add `.com` in multiple `a` tag on run time using Jquery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var a = $('a').text();
  $('a').attr('href',a+'.com');
});
```

Comment: Do you really want the link's TEXT (+ `.com`)  to be used as an `href` value ?

Comment: Yeah... looks little bit strange at the end. Please, update your question to make requirements obvious. If you need to convert `a`-content into URL, accepted answer is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `.each()` like below:-

Working example:-

```js
//convert $ to jQuery if you are using older jQuery library
$(document).ready(function($){
  $('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href')+".com")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="abc">Abc</a><br>
<a href="def">Def</a><br>
```

Note:- It's required that your links have `https://` or `http://` in it's href. Because only having `abc.com` will not tell that the link have to be `https://....` or `http://....` to the browser and it will lead to ambiguity sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('a').each(function () {
        this.href = this.innerHTML + '.com';
    });
});
```